# I need more info about Puppeteer page.metrics and queryObjects

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, puppeteer

I'm using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to find a memory leak issue. I'm using puppeteer's [page.metrics()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagemetrics) API but I am having trouble understanding each properties meaning. All my values in the metrics keep increasing in value over time. Is this expected? Or is this an indication that there might be a serious memory leak?

The properties which are growing in value as the app runs are:
`JSEventListeners, Nodes, LayoutCount, RecalcStyleCount, LayoutDuration, RecalcStyleDuration, ScriptDuration, TaskDuration, JSHeapUsedSize, JSHeapTotalSize`

The information about this stuff is very sparse and also I keep seeing people refer to `page.queryObjects` as another way to find memory leaks. But I cannot find any information about how to use this API and what to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/index.md):

> #### [page.metrics()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.metrics.md)
>
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)>> Object containing metrics as key/value pairs.
>
>   - `Timestamp` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> The timestamp when the metrics sample was taken.
>   - `Documents` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Number of documents in the page.
>   - `Frames` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Number of frames in the page.
>   - `JSEventListeners` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Number of events in the page.
>   - `Nodes` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Number of DOM nodes in the page.
>   - `LayoutCount` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Total number of full or partial page layout.
>   - `RecalcStyleCount` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Total number of page style recalculations.
>   - `LayoutDuration` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Combined durations of all page layouts.
>   - `RecalcStyleDuration` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Combined duration of all page style recalculations.
>   - `ScriptDuration` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Combined duration of JavaScript execution.
>   - `TaskDuration` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Combined duration of all tasks performed by the browser.
>   - `JSHeapUsedSize` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Used JavaScript heap size.
>   - `JSHeapTotalSize` <[number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)> Total JavaScript heap size.
>
> > **NOTE** All timestamps are in monotonic time: monotonically increasing time in seconds since an arbitrary point in the past.
>
> #### [page.queryObjects(prototypeHandle)](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.queryobjects.md)
>
> - `prototypeHandle` <[JSHandle](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.jshandle.md)> A handle to the object prototype.
> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[JSHandle](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.jshandle.md)>> Promise which resolves to a handle to an array of objects with this prototype.
>
> The method iterates the JavaScript heap and finds all the objects with the given prototype.
>
> ```
> // Create a Map object
> await page.evaluate(() => window.map = new Map());
> // Get a handle to the Map object prototype
> const mapPrototype = await page.evaluateHandle(() => Map.prototype);
> // Query all map instances into an array
> const mapInstances = await page.queryObjects(mapPrototype);
> // Count amount of map objects in heap
> const count = await page.evaluate(maps => maps.length, mapInstances);
> await mapInstances.dispose();
> await mapPrototype.dispose();
> ```
>
> Shortcut for `page.mainFrame().executionContext().queryObjects(prototypeHandle)`

---

The `page.metrics()` method returns the result of the Chrome DevTools Protocol [`Performance.getMetrics`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance#method-getMetrics):

> #### Performance.getMetrics
>
> Retrieve current values of run-time metrics.
>
> RETURN OBJECT
>
> - `metrics` **array [Metric](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance#type-Metric)**
>
>   - Current values for run-time metrics.

On the other hand, the Chrome DevTools Protocol that accompanies the `page.queryObjects()` method is [`Runtime.queryObjects`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#method-queryObjects):

> #### Runtime.queryObjects
>
> PARAMETERS
>
> - `prototypeObjectId` **[RemoteObjectId](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#type-RemoteObjectId)**
>
>   - Identifier of the prototype to return objects for.
> - `objectGroup` **string** (optional)
>
>   - Symbolic group name that can be used to release the results.
>
> RETURN OBJECT
>
> - `objects` **[RemoteObject](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#type-RemoteObject)**
>
>   - Array with objects.

---

The source code for [`page.metrics()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.metrics.md) and [`page.queryObjects()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.queryobjects.md) can be found on GitHub.