# Understanding Chrome DevTools Performance.getMetrics() results

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer's page.metrics() which calls the DevTools protocol [Performance.getMetrics()](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance#method-getMetrics) 
Here is a sample of the returned data :

```
{
   Timestamp: 672.244221,
   Documents: 3,
   Frames: 2,
   JSEventListeners: 2,
   Nodes: 4116,
   LayoutCount: 3,
   RecalcStyleCount: 2,
   LayoutDuration: 0.136179,
   RecalcStyleDuration: 0.027681,
   ScriptDuration: 0.188817,
   TaskDuration: 0.563811,
   JSHeapUsedSize: 2959520,
   JSHeapTotalSize: 5132288
}
```

The only documentation i could find for these numbers is in [puppeteer's documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagemetrics)
and it is basically this:

> - Timestamp  The timestamp when the metrics sample was taken.
> - Documents  Number of documents in the page.
> - Frames  Number of frames in the page.
> - JSEventListeners  Number of events in the page.
> - Nodes  Number of DOM nodes in the page.
> - LayoutCount  Total number of full or partial page layout.
> - RecalcStyleCount  Total number of page style recalculations.
> - LayoutDuration  Combined durations of all page layouts.
> - RecalcStyleDuration  Combined duration of all page style recalculations.
> - ScriptDuration  Combined duration of JavaScript execution.
> - TaskDuration  Combined duration of all tasks performed by the browser.
> - JSHeapUsedSize  Used JavaScript heap size.
> - JSHeapTotalSize  Total JavaScript heap size.

I would really like to get more details regarding these numbers, and specifically to answer these questions:

1. TaskDuration is significantly larger then the sum of ScriptDuration, LayoutDuration and RecalculateStyleDuration

   - Where was the rest of the time wasted ?
   - What other measurements i can take to account for that missing time ?
2. What are documents and frames ?

Comment: Note - a similar question has been asked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630430/i-need-more-info-about-puppeteer-page-metrics-and-queryobjects

but the answer only cited the same documentation in puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your first question, Chrome also calculates the system time and idle time (visible on the performance tab in Devtools), and there's also the total time calculated.

I'm not exactly sure what the system and idle time measure, but I have seen it in the screenshot below:

[chrome devtools performance tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKZsc.png)